# What does the cog wheel in Ubuntu's Settings > Search do?

Tags: 18.04, gui, search

I just did a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04.1 in a virtual machine. After fully updating the system via the command line, I looked at various options in **Settings**.

[image: cog wheel]

The bottom row of the *Search* window has a cog wheel on the right and up and down arrows on the left. If an item is selected, the arrow keys move it up or down in the list.

But what does the cog wheel [image: cog wheel] do? It stays grey whether or not an item in the list is selected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cogwheel lets you customise the search locations (for *Files*).

[image]

> *But why doesn't this work on Ubuntu 18.04?*

Because Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't have [`tracker`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/tracker) pre-installed.

`tracker` is a *metadata database, indexer and search tool* for GNOME. It increases the speed of searching in the Files app and also supports full-text search. But this comes with a huge cost, it causes high CPU use and/or other performance issues.

That's why Ubuntu developers decided to ship Ubuntu 17.10 and 18.04 without `tracker` (see [known issues](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes)).

If you manually install `tracker` and re-login, the cogwheel should be activated.